# VB.NET 2 Rows being added to datatable instead of just 1

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Here's the code:

```
    Private Sub AddNewDgvRow(dgv As DataGridView)
      Dim dt As DataTable = dgv.DataSource.DataSource.Client
      Dim myRow As DataRow = dt.NewRow
      dt.Rows.Add(myRow)                      <-------- adds 2 rows at this point
    End Sub
```

The problem is that this code is adding 2 rows, and I don't know why.

dgv.Datasource yields a BindingSource, and dgv.Datasource.Datasource a DataSet

Tried just the dt.NewRow without the dt.Rows.Add() and it takes it syntactically but then I get an instance error down the line. I need .NewRow to create the schema record defaults.

Any ideas? VB.NET in VS2013.2 Thank you so much!

-HB

Comment: Something else is adding the second row. In which event do you call this method?

Comment: Just getting ready to update the post. I (was) clicking on a new record line in the DGV and catching it there. Stepping through the code -- that ONE line produced two records. I should step into the code further -- just now an afterthought. However, I just created a button and ran the routine from there and I did not have the issue. Will get back after further investigation. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Not sure what it is... click on new row fires a Row Validation in which this statement: "Dim dgv As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)" increments the dgv.RowCount from x to x+2 on my debug WatchList. That's as deep as I know how to get. I can workaround it by using another control to implement the method above but am still curious why...

Comment: Is "Allow User to Add Rows" set?  It that is true, no code is needed to add the row.  Thus, the DataGridView is automatically adding it and then your code (in AddNewDgvRow) is adding it again.

Comment: @Phaedra -- Yes, this was the case. I knew this, but I was catching a CellEnter procedure that was creating an error as the logic assumed an existing record, so I started creating a workaround for that by creating a separate new record routine. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: how do you mark an answer as correct so that the responder gets credit?

Comment: I added my comment as an answer so you can click the checkbox to accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "Allow User to Add Rows" set? It that is true, no code is needed to add the row. Thus, the DataGridView is automatically adding it and then your code (in AddNewDgvRow) is adding it again.

As you referenced in the comment on your original post regarding CellEnter event, sometimes a programmer may want to use DataGridView's built-in functionality, and sometimes we want more control.